# How long will a Google Form's public url last?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-app, google-forms

I have a google form that I am having pushed out through a Kiosk App and that google form is going to be used for the foreseeable future. Since I am not a Network Engineer or Systems Administrator in my network, the only way of getting the webview element in my App to display the Google form is to hard code it's URL because I have nowhere from which to dynamically update the URL in my App at the moment.

I am also not the Chrome Administrator and because of this I need to send my packaged Kiosk App off site to have it pushed out to my building's Chromebooks which means that for every update that I do, I need to re-package it and have the Chrome guy update it manually.

Since I and many others would prefer to not perform the task noted above on a frequent basis, I am trying to find out how long the Google Form's url will last and/or how often we can expect it to change if it does ever change.

Answer (score 1):

Surely if you have any concerns over the link changing, you can just set up a redirect from a domain you control.

That way even if the kiosk form gets upgraded from Google to something else, you can just change your redirect without recompiling and redistributing your application.

Comment: I would like to do that, but unfortunately the IT department isn't going to spend a ton of resources and time to implement that. Also, they aren't going to let me set it up myself. I am just wondering how long a google form url will last.